# How to create a Live Folder programmatically (send an intent to the home screen)?

Tags: android, homescreen, android-livefolders

I'm wondering how I can go about creating a Live Folder programmatically, and what permissions I would need to request in my app.

I've read a bunch of articles and postings about how to create a LF via the normal home-long-press method.

I would assume I need to send a specific intent to the home screen, but I can't seem to find the name of the home screen activity to send to, nor the intent to send.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I go about doing this?

You don't. You cannot add live folders, app widgets, etc. to the user's home screen. Users need to request them via a long-click on the home screen or other mechanism that the home screen provides.

Moreover, please bear in mind that there are quite a few home screens out there, so even if one has some undocumented API that would let you do this, the others most likely will not.

Comment: There actually seems to be a way of adding launcher; a lot of apps have taken to adding icons to your home screen for themselves, though I haven't seen any create folders.

Comment: @Ken: see the last paragraph in my answer.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether there was a documented way of adding an app, but not a folder.

Comment: @Ken: Not that I am aware of, sorry.